# Limit size of diffable data source snapshots after calling performFetch

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview, diffabledatasource, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

## Problem

After executing an [`NSBatchBatchInsertRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchinsertrequest) and calling [`fetchedResultsController.performFetch()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscon%E2%80%A6), the frc’s delegate method [`controller(_:didChangeContentWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate/3235742-controller) is called with a `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, NSManagedObjectID>` that unexpectedly contains *all* data in Core Data (even though I've only just inserted *new* data).

## Code

Here's how the `NSFetchedResultsController` is created:

```
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<MyManagedObject>(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: persistentContainer.viewContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil
    )
```

The `NSFetchRequest`:

```
    let fetchRequest = MyManagedObject.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "value", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 10
```

The snapshot is applied in this `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` method below.

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeContentWith snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference) {
    dataSource.apply(snapshot as NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, NSManagedObjectID>, animatingDifferences: false)
}
```

## Details

- The sample app receives 10,000 `Item` instances every 5 seconds and runs an `NSBatchInsertRequest` on a new background context with `performAndWait` to convert and store the `Item`s as `MyManagedObject` instances.
- `performFetch()` is then called on `main`.
- Calling `performFetch()` ensures a new snapshot is provided in [`controller(_:didChangeContentWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate/3235742-controller), which the data source can [`apply(_:animatingDifferences:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource/3375795-apply) to update the UI.
- The items populate a `UICollectionView`, which is hooked up to a `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, NSManagedObjectID>`.

  - When the data source is asked to make a cell for a specific `NSManagedObjectID`, the right `MyManagedObject` for that `NSManagedObjectID` using `fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.object(with:)`.
  - Then the `MyManagedObject` is converted into an `Item`, which is finally used to configure the cell.

## Attempt at a solution

The most obvious solution to me was implementing this delegate method only, but that method doesn't seem to get called:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeContentWith diff: CollectionDifference<NSManagedObjectID>) {
    print(diff)
}
```

I don't want the UI to stutter and hang when I'm fetching the data. I think that the reason that's happening is because my snapshots are huge. My guess why they're huge is because my fetch request fetches all the data (but I only want to add *new* data to the snapshot). To fix that, I've tried to setting `fetchLimit` to a small number like 2, but that just causes only 2 items to be fetched at all. I think I could workaround that by updating `fetchOffset`, but that approach could get messy as I scroll around. Adjusting `fetchBatchSize` doesn't make a difference. Memory is not leaking either. And FWIW, I'm applying the snapshots in a background queue, but that also doesn't seem to improve the UI stuttering.

I want to store items to Core Data as I get them, and then only fetch from the persistent store when scrolling to off-screen cells. That appears to be happening because I can see the data source only requests cells for index paths near the visible range when the snapshot is applied (even though the vertical scroll bar of the collection view is shrinking over time). *But* the size of snapshots (= the total number of items received until now) is ever increasing.

I can get the current snapshot and only append the items missing from the new snapshot, but that will still require me to go through a snapshot of unbounded size. How can I avoid doing that and load lots of data without the UI stuttering? I'm only inserting *new* data into Core Data, so why am I getting *all* the data in the snapshots?

Comment: *This may or may not be possible, I am a Core Data noob :) any guidance helps